# Visual Studio 2008 debug error

Tags: visual-studio, callstack

I have a very annoying issue with visual studio 2008 sp1 on windows 7 64 bit.

The software we are working on uses a client that connects to a windows service. so, when i do a debug, i debug on 2 processes, the client and the service.

When hitting a breakpoint on the service, and using F10, F11 for 20-30 times aprox, I get an "Visual Studio is busy doing an internal operation ..." message, after which the debugger throws me to another place. If I look at the call stack, there is a message "Evaluation of:". above it, the call stack where I currently am, and below it, there is the call stack where I was before the error occurred.

here is something similar: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/vsdebug/thread/4c30e3f4-587e-4f14-8cec-8663d268c55c

I tried installing latest updates, cleaning solution, deleting dll files, *ncb, *suo. nothing worked :|

It's not related to the wpf editor bug.

Thanks.

Comment: You're debugging both client and service. Can you be certain that the point at which it's hanging isn't waiting on some form of information from the other session?

Comment: I'm 99,9% sure that it's not waiting. it is not an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Now I looked into the output panel, and after I am thrown to another code, I got an message : "A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in xxxxxxxxxxx.dll"

Answer (score 0):

This is barely an answer, but I had the same problem with VS 2008 (updated to KB972221) running on 32-bit Windows XP.

The key seems to be running two instances of VS2008 at the same time.
I had a client/server setup and was running each of these executables via its own VS2008 instance. The server was multi-threaded, the client I think single-threaded.

Like you, I had set a breakpoint and was then F10 stepping through the code when I had the same experience of VS hanging for a while then dumping me elsewhere in the code following an `Evaluation of:` message in the call stack.

However, I changed to simply running the client executable on its own, with just the server running in debug mode with VS2008, and the problem never recurred (to date!).

So maybe the workaround is simply to stick to a single VS2008 session.